# Group based on the higher out of 3 cells

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have 3 cells N, O, P with numeric values  13, 8, 10
in Q , I want to show a 'Group' 1 or 2 or 3 based on which cell is higher than the other 2
IF(OR(N2>O2,N2>P2),1,IF(OR(O2>N2,O2>P2),2,IF(OR(P2>N2,P2>O2),3,"")))  = error
another i tried

```
IF(OR(N3>O3,N3>P3),1,IF(OR(O3>N3,O3>P3),2,IF(OR(P3>N3,P3>O3),3,"")))
```

now on this one, if N3=0, O3=1, P3=0 then I get 2 as a result
but if N3=1, O3=2, P3=3  I also get 2 when it should give me 3

what am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to go the route of nested `IF()` functions, you could try:

```
=IF(AND(N3>O3,N3>P3),1,IF(AND(O3>N3,O3>P3),2,IF(AND(P3>N3,P3>O3),3,"")))
```

Note how I used `AND()` instead of `OR()`. If you are open to a different kind of solution, try something else:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(N3:P3,MAX(N3:P3))=1,MATCH(MAX(N3:P3),N3:P3,0),"")
```

I included an `COUNTIF()` just because you included `""` as the `FALSE` parameter to account for duplicate max values. If you get rid of the nested `COUNTIF()` you'd get the position of the first hightest value.